# Why my code didnt synchronize with phone battery?

Tags: java, android

I try some code but it not sync with my phone battery
Ex: my phone battery 72% but it always show 100% not going up or down. This code doesnt request any special permission

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context mContext;
    private TextView mViewInfo;
    private TextView mViewPercentage;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            mViewInfo.setText("Battery Scale : " + scale);

            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            mViewInfo.setText(mViewInfo.getText() + "\nBattery Level : " + level);

            float percentage = level/ (float) scale;
            mProgressStatus = (int)((percentage)*100);
            mViewPercentage.setText("" + mProgressStatus + "%");
            mViewInfo.setText(mViewInfo.getText() + "\nPercentage : " + mProgressStatus + "%");
            mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, iFilter);
        mViewInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
        mViewPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_percentage);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    }
}
```

I want my code will sync with phone battery
There always say all 100% its suppose to be sync with battery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by this part of your code:

```
int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
mViewInfo.setText("Battery Scale : " + scale);

int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
mViewInfo.setText(mViewInfo.getText() + "\nBattery Level : " + level);

float percentage = level/ (float) scale;
mProgressStatus = (int)((percentage)*100);
```

If you noticed, you'll see that you're using `intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)` for both **scale** and **level**.

Which means you're getting the exact same value, so when you go do your calculations of `level / (float) scale;` you're pretty much doing `NUM / NUM`, which will **always** equal to 1. Then when you do `1 * 100`, it'll always equal to 100.

What you need to do is replace:

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
```

with:

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```